# Prove that $G/N$ is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Below is a homework problem I have gotten stuck on. I would really appreciate a hint, but please do not just give the answer away.

> Let $G \subset \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that each $m \in G$ is
>   upper triangular with a nonzero determinant.  Let $N = \left\{
>  \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&b\\ 0&1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) : b \in
>  \mathbb{R}\right\}$. Prove that:
>
> • $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
>
> • $G/N$ is abelian.

**Solution**: Let $m \in G$; then $\exists \alpha, \beta, \delta \in \mathbb{R} : m = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
\alpha & \beta \\ 0&\delta
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$; $\alpha\delta \neq 0$. $m$ is invertible, hence $m^{-1} =  \frac{1}{\alpha \delta}\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
\delta & -\beta \\ 0&\alpha
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$. Let's look at $m N m^{-1}$. 
\begin{align*}
m N m^{-1} &= \left\{ \left(\begin{matrix}
\alpha & \beta \\ 0&\delta
\end{matrix} \right) \left(\begin{matrix}
1&b\\ 0&1
\end{matrix} \right) \frac{1}{\alpha \delta}\left(\begin{matrix}
\delta & -\beta \\ 0&\alpha
\end{matrix} \right) : \alpha, \beta, \delta, b \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \\
&= \left\{\left(\begin{matrix}
\alpha& \alpha b + \beta \\ 0&\delta
\end{matrix} \right) \frac{1}{\alpha \delta}\left(\begin{matrix}
\delta & -\beta \\ 0&\alpha
\end{matrix} \right) : \alpha, \beta, \delta, b \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \\
&= \left\{ \frac{1}{\alpha\delta}\left( \begin{matrix}
\alpha\delta& -\beta\alpha + \alpha^2 b + \beta\alpha \\ 0 &\alpha\delta
\end{matrix} \right) : \alpha, \beta, \delta, b \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \\
&= \left\{\left( \begin{matrix}
1& \frac{\alpha b}{\delta} \\ 0 & 1
\end{matrix} \right) : \alpha, \beta, \delta, b \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \\
\end{align*}
Since $\alpha \neq 0 $ and $ \delta \neq 0$, it follows that $\frac{\alpha b}{\delta}$ is a valid real number. Therefore $mNm^{-1} \in G$, hence $N$ is normal.

Now consider $G/N$: the group of right cosets of $N$ in $G$. Let $Nm_1$ and $Nm_2$ be two right cosets of $N$ in $G$. Then 
\begin{align*}
Nm_1Nm_2 &= Nm_1m_2\\
&= N  \left(\begin{matrix}
a & b  \\ 0& d
\end{matrix} \right)  \left(\begin{matrix}
\alpha & \beta \\ 0&\delta
\end{matrix} \right)\\
&= N  \left(\begin{matrix}
a\alpha & a\beta+ b \delta  \\ 0& d\delta
\end{matrix} \right) \\
....
\end{align*}

---

This is where I get stuck. I figure there must be a matrix in $n \in N$ such that, for any two upper triangular matrices $m_1$ and $m_2, m_1 n m_2 = m_2 n m_1$, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Try this one: What should the matrix $m_2m_1$ look like?

Comment: Define $n \in N$ by $1$ on the diagonal and $\frac{\alpha b + \beta d}{a \beta + b \delta}$. Then $m_1 m_2$ are the same modulo an element in $N$, namely $n$

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94162/proving-that-g-n-is-an-abelian-group/94168#94168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never know whether to call cosets left or right, but $G/N$ stands for cosets of the form $gN$ with $g \in G$.  I guess people call these left cosets, even though you are multiplying by $N$ on the right.  Anyway, it does not materially affect your calculation, but I thought I would mention it.

To show that $G/N$ is abelian, you need
$$
(m_1 N) (m_2 N) = (m_2 N) (m_1 N),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
m_1 m_2 N = m_2 m_1 N,
$$
which in turn is equivalent to $m_1^{-1} m_2^{-1} m_1 m_2 \in N$.  This expression is called the commutator of $m_1^{-1}$ and $m_2^{-1}$ (the inverses just appear because of how we wrote the initial calculation).  So you just need to consider $m_1^{-1} m_2^{-1} m_1 m_2$ and argue that it must have $1$'s on the diagonal.

Further hint:

> Instead of writing out the entire matrix multiplication, it is more transparent if you observe that the diagonal entries in the product of two upper triangular matrices are the products of the diagonal entries in those two upper triangular matrices.

Comment: Thanks Michael; as for your note on notation I am following Herstein's (which I am starting to realize deviates from the usual algebraic notation), and he defines $G/N$ as the collection of right cosets of $N$ in $G$. 

I see the proof now, I was just missing that commutator element. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you sure that his definition of right coset is $Ng$ as well?  I haven't used Herstein's book, but I find it odd that elements of $G/N$ would be $Ng$ and not $gN$.  Of course, if $N$ is normal, then $Ng = gN$, so it does not really matter!  But it does matter if $N$ is any subgroup and we are talking about simply the set of left (or right) cosets.

Comment: I'm positive, I've got the page where he defines $G/N$ right in front of me. But this is just one of many notational peculiarities that Herstein has; it has been driving my instructor mad.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the map $$G \to \mathbf R^\times \times \mathbf R^\times$$

given by  $$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} a&b\\ 0&c \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \mapsto (a, ac).$$

It's easy to check that it is a homomorphism, and its kernel is precisely $N$. Therefore $N$ is normal in $G$, and since $G/N$ injects into the abelian group $\mathbf R^\times \times \mathbf R^\times$, it is abelian.

Comment: Nice solution - is there a reason you use $ac$ in the second factor instead of just $c$?

Comment: @MichaelJoyce Thanks! Not really. Being the determinant, I thought it was a natural choice.

Comment: The book I am following introduces homomorphisms in the following chapter, so I think the author's intent was for the student to solve without such tools.

But I will definitely review this solution after I read the chapter on homomorphisms, since it looks so simple. Thanks!

Comment: @A.E No problem. My pleasure!