# Is $G/N$ isomorphic to $\mathbb R ?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$$G=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & \ \ \ \ a^{-1}\end{bmatrix} : a,b \in \mathbb R;a>0 \right\}$$

$$ \hspace{-1.1in}N=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} :b\in \mathbb R\right\}$$

Which of the following are true?

(A) $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ under addition.

(B) $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\{a ∈ \mathbb R : a > 0\}$ under multiplication.

(C) There is a proper normal subgroup $N'$  of $G$ which properly contains $N$.

(D) $N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ under addition.

Option $D$ is not true I figured. Option $C$ is possible as every subgroup is contained in a normal subgroup that is the normalizer . But how can I tel if that one is a ***proper*** subgroup or not ?

Also more than one correct answers is a possibility and I'm not sure about options $A$ and $B.$

Please give me hints. I think I can work out from thereon.

Thanks.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood : thank you for the edit.

Comment: No problem. Try to add some work that you've done.

Comment: What made you decide $N$ is not isomorphic to {the reals under addition}? Did you try multiplying two elements of $N$ to see what you get?

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 2):

Try to show that the map
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    0 & a^{-1} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
\mapsto a
$$
is a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $(\mathbb R^+,\cdot)$.

What is kernel of this homomorphism? What can you say based on this using [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem)?

This should help you to see that (B) is true.

---

If it helps, you can have a look at a similar answer here: [Proving that $G/N$ is an abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94162/proving-that-g-n-is-an-abelian-group/94168#94168)