# If S is a normal subgroup, identify the quotient group G/S. What are the $\varphi(G)$'s?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

The following is an exercise from Artin's Algebra: (Kiefer Sutherland's voice)

> Let G be the group of upper triangular real matrices $\begin{bmatrix}
> a & b\\ 
> 0 & d
> \end{bmatrix}$ with a and d different from zero. For each of the following subsets, determine whether or not S is a subgroup, and whether or not S is a normal subgroup. If S is a normal subgroup, identify the quotient group $G/S$.
>
> (i) S is the subset defined by b = O.
>
> (ii) S is the subset defined by d = 1.
>
> (iii) S is the subset defined by a = d.

The following questions are related:

[How the quotient group of following matrix group looks like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199289/how-the-quotient-group-of-following-matrix-group-looks-like)
[Proving that $G/N$ is an abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94162/proving-that-g-n-is-an-abelian-group)

I found a solution by Blake Griffith linked [here](https://github.com/cowlicks/algebraic-structures-373k/tree/master/homework/h3).

The following is a screenshot of the solution:

[image]

[image]

The following are my questions:

1. How is $S$ is the $\ker$ for iii? I computed the kernel to be $$\begin{bmatrix}
   x_{11} & x_{12}\\ 
   0 & x_{22}
   \end{bmatrix}$$

where $x_{21} = 0, x_{12} \in \mathbb R, x_{11} \ne 0 \ne x_{22}$. But how do we conclude $x_{11} = x_{22}$? I think I'm missing something slightly because the solution was (ii) was incredibly inventing:

2. Is this correction to ii correct?

> For ii, we set
>   $$\varphi(X)=X\pmatrix{\frac{1}{x_{11}}&\frac{x_{12}}{x_{11}}\\0&1}=\pmatrix{1&2x_{12}\\
>  \frac{x_{21}}{x_{11}}&\frac{x_{21}x_{12}}{x_{11}}+x_{22}}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$$
>   to get $S$.

It was pointed out this is wrong, but I think I can correct this.

> For ii, we set
>   $$\varphi(X)=X\pmatrix{\frac{1}{x_{11}}&\frac{-x_{12}}{x_{11}}\\0&1}=\pmatrix{1&0\\
>  \frac{x_{21}}{x_{11}}&\frac{-x_{21}x_{12}}{x_{11}}+x_{22}}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$$
>   to get $S$.

3. Does the $G'$ matter? I think it doesn't, but I want to confirm.
4. What are the $\varphi(G)$'s?

For ii, I think $\varphi(G)$ is all of $d \ne 0, b \in \mathbb R$ in $$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\frac 1 a & \frac b a \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2b\\ 
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}$$

For iii, I think $\varphi(G)=I_2$ because

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\frac 1 a & \frac b {-ad} \\ 
0 & \frac{1}{d}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

What does it mean that $\varphi(G)$ is just the identity of $G'$? $|G/S|=1$ I think

Answer (score 1):

Though you didn't question this, I found it rather strange that the verifications of being closed under multiplication are actually reduced to verification of being closed under *squaring* an element. I think it's not enough in general. However, showing that these sets are closed under multiplication takes the same effort..

To your questions,

1. Neither of these maps $\phi$ seem to work. I guess, they are not even group homomorphisms.
   As it stands - you correctly calculated - $\phi\pmatrix{a&b\\0&d}=\pmatrix{1&2b\\0&d}$ for ii) and $\phi\pmatrix{a&b\\0&d}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ for iii). 
   Neither does produce the corresponding set $S$ as the preimage of the identity matrix.

   I thought, maybe that $X$ is superfluous in the definitions, so speaking about e.g. $\phi\pmatrix{a&b\\0&d}=\pmatrix{1/a&b/a\\0&1}$, but those don't work either.
2. $G'$ doesn't really matter, can be any ambient group. It's the image of $\phi$ what matters. (Once we find better candidates for the $\phi$'s).
3. Your calculations and conclusions are correct. However, we have to find better $\phi$'s, or just describe the quotients as they are.

Comment: Berci why should $S=\varphi(G)?$ We should have $S=\ker(\varphi)$. I believe $S$ is correct for ii. Do you disagree? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, $\ker\phi$. Well, $\pmatrix{a&b\\0&d}$ will be taken to $I$ iff $d=1$ and $b=0$, which is not the same condition as $S$ in ii).

Comment: For ii, we set $\varphi(X)=X\pmatrix{\frac{1}{x_{11}}&\frac{x_{12}}{x_{11}}\\0&1}=\pmatrix{1&2x_{12}\\ \frac{x_{21}}{x_{11}}&\frac{x_{21}x_{12}}{x_{11}}+x_{22}}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ to get $S$. Am I incorrect? This is incredibly inventive if correct. Why do you solve $\varphi(G)=I_2$ to compute $S$?

Comment: That's what '*kernel*' means: the preimage of the identity element. I think, your calculation is correct. And in the solution we have the restriction $x_{12}=0$ which is not there in the definition of $S$.

Comment: Just a note: as you see, this solution is not clear. You could have made it easier if you just start it by your own. This half-solution just takes extra efforts..

Comment: Berci, how about for ii, we set $\varphi(X)=X\pmatrix{\frac{1}{x_{11}}&\frac{-x_{12}}{x_{11}}\\0&1}=\pmatrix{1&0\\ \frac{x_{21}}{x_{11}}&\frac{x_{21}x_{12}}{x_{11}}+x_{22}}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ to get $S$? For computing the kernel, why do you solve $\varphi(G)=I_2$ rather than solve $\varphi(X)=I_2$? $\varphi(G)$ is an image (it is constant) not a function. I think solving $\varphi(G)=I_2$ is kind of meaningless, with all due respect.

Comment: I'm not sure we get a homomorphism such a way. Who verified these are homomorphisms? I suggest first just try to consider the quotient groups, as they are. How many parameters can describe an element in the quotient, etc.?

Comment: What do you mean? You said the original solution has $x_{12}=0$. But in the new solution, $\varphi(X)=X\pmatrix{\frac{1}{x_{11}}&\frac{-x_{12}}{x_{11}}\\0&1}=\pmatrix{1&0\\ \frac{x_{21}}{x_{11}}&\frac{x_{21}x_{12}}{x_{11}}+x_{22}}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$, we no longer have $x_{12}=0$. Correct?

Comment: $\phi(G)$ is a *set*; the set of all $\phi(X)$'s where $X\in G$. (So, by the way, $x_{21}=0$ always, by definition of $G$.)

Comment: I mean, we don't only need $\phi^{-1}(I_2)=S$, we also need that $\phi$ respects multiplication, i.e. is a homomorphism. This is not checked (and I guess is not even true) in the solution.

Comment: Berci, oh I understand! Thank you so much! The solution was actually really hard to think of. In any case, I'm glad to that I later found out that all I have to do is compute the cosets instead of come up with an explicit homomorphism.

Comment: Berci, do you agree with the solution of Mark Lindberg and Travis Schedler linked [here in pages 4 and 5](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e3f2/38d10d91658b43a661b6e82497d3f607c788.pdf) or the solution of Takumi Murayama linked [here in pages 11-13](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b01902113/artin-sols.pdf)? Thank you so so much!

Comment: @Jack: You should try and invent the solution yourself instead of wildly searching. Or just follow egreg's or my proposed lines (egreg also suggests the correct $\phi$'s). Anyway, these are better..

Comment: I did. I computed the cosets and thought that's all there was to it, but when I looked up the answers, it turns out computing the cosets is not the same as identifying them, which seems to usually involve saying what they are isomorphic to, and it has something isomorphic to something we commonly know like $\mathbb R^{\times}$ or $\mathbb R^{+} \times \mathbb R^{+}$. I think this is what Munkres would call an "open question". We know the coset, but don't really understand what the coset is until we identify it. I did not wildly search.

Comment: By the way, I have a new question on this linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957544/choice-of-representatives-to-partition-by-a-subgroup-of-gl-2-mathbb-r-of-ano).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in the proposed solution.

The remark that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix} a^{-1} & -ba^{-1}d^{-1} \\ 0 & d^{-1} \end{bmatrix}
$$
is correct and useful.

### Case (i), call the set $S_1$

The set $S_1$ is not empty, because $I$ (the identity matrix) belongs to it. Also the inverse of every element in $S_1$ is again in $S_1$.

Closure under multiplication *requires* two *arbitrary* elements of $S_1$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} a' & 0 \\ 0 & d' \end{bmatrix}^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix} aa' & 0 \\ 0 & dd' \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\in S_1
$$
In order to show $S_1$ is not normal, an *explicit* example should be given. The computation is correct, but stating that
$$
gsg^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} a & b'(d-a)d' \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}
$$
is not sufficient; however we can take $a=2$, $d=1$, $a'=b'=d'=1$ and we'd be done.

Note that choosing $a\ne d$ is very important: the same computation applied to the set in (iii) shows *that* subgroup is normal!

### Case (ii)

This case, apart from the glitch about the product, is correct.

### Case (iii)

The same as above applies.

### Identifying the quotient groups

For $S_2$, the group in (ii), you can observe that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a & b-1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and that the first term in the right-hand side is in $S_2$, depending only on $d$. This gives the idea to consider the map $\varphi_2\colon S\to\mathbb{R}^*$ (nonzero real numbers with respect to multiplication) defined by
$$
\varphi_2\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}\right)=d
$$
This is seen to be a (surjective) homomorphism, with kernel exactly $S_2$.

Comment: Thank you so so much egreg! I will look at this morning.

Comment: egreg, do you agree with the solution of Mark Lindberg and Travis Schedler linked [here in pages 4 and 5](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e3f2/38d10d91658b43a661b6e82497d3f607c788.pdf) or the solution of Takumi Murayama linked [here in pages 11-13](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b01902113/artin-sols.pdf)? Thank you so so much!

Comment: Why is $$\ker \varphi_3 = S_3$$? I computed $$\ker \varphi_3 = G \cap \{b=0\}$$ By the way, I have a new question on this linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957544/choice-of-representatives-to-partition-by-a-subgroup-of-gl-2-mathbb-r-of-ano). I think this doesn't work for a little similar reason why $(iii)$ solution of Blake Griffith doesn't work: no guarantee that $a=d$?

Comment: Please double check: $G/S_2$ is isomorphic to $R^{\times}$ and $G/S_3$ is isomorphic to $R^{+}$?

Comment: Please double check: $G/S_2$ is isomorphic to $R^{\times}$ and $G/S_3$ is isomorphic to $R^{+}$? I think Takumi Murayama would say $G/S_2$ and $G/S_3$ are both isomorphic to $R^{\times}$ (I asked about his answer in another question linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957544/choice-of-representatives-to-partition-by-a-subgroup-of-gl-2-mathbb-r-of-ano).)